# Keep the ratio of a component using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have an image of size (width, height).

I want to keep the ratio of the image (height = 1.2 * width).

I want to center this image in the container.
So to have an empty margin around, what can be done is setting a maximum width equal to 90% of the container and a maximum height also equal to 90% of the container.

So the image should take all the space it can but can't excess 90% of the width or 90% of the height (of it's container).

Here is the structure of the code :

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
ImageComponent blueDragon = new ImageComponent("my_image.png"); // A JPanel containing the image
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
// Code
panel.add(blueDragon, c);
```

How to achieve the described behavior ? Thanks

Comment: This is not really how GridBagLayout was built to be used, and you may need to either create your own layout manager or use a 3rd party one such as MigLayout

Comment: Okay thanks for the idea ! Unfortunately it seems like MigLayout would not work for this problem too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902256/miglayout-how-to-resize-the-height-proportionally-to-the-width-keeping-the-asp). So I think that I will need to create my own Component/Layout to achieve it.

Comment: *So to have an empty margin around,* - set an EmptyBorder for the panel. Set the layout manager of the panel to use a BorderLayout. Then add a label using a `StretchIcon` to the panel. The [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) will grow/shrink as the frame size is changed. It can be configured to keep the aspect ration of the image.